# Issue validating AWS ACM certification using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, certificate

Disclaimer: I am new to both AWS and Terraform.

I am testing something out and when deploying my code, I keep running into the same error after running Terraform Apply

```
Error describing created certificate: Expected certificate to be issued but was in state PENDING_VALIDATION
```

I have tried running my code multiple times and it times out at 60 minutes each time. I cannot exceed 60 minutes due to a timeout of my session.

For this, there were two steps:

1. Create the Hosted Zone in a **account 2** (this was done by a colleague and completed successfully)

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "<example>" {

  name  = "<domain name>"
```

2.Created the A record, ACM cert, validation record, and validation object in **account 1**

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "<service>" {
  provider = aws.account2
  zone_id  = data.terraform_remote_state.account2.outputs.route53_<example>_zone_id[0]
  name     = var.domain_name
  type     = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = aws_alb.<service>.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_alb.<service>.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "<service>" {
  domain_name       = var.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "<service>_validation" {
  provider = aws.account2
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.<service>.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.terraform_remote_state.account2.outputs.route53_<example>_zone_id[0]
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "<service>" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.<service>.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.<service>_validation : record.fqdn]
  

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
  }
}
```

I have looked at quite a few examples online and cannot figure out yet where I went wrong. This is the final piece of my Terraform Apply.

I have checked the AWS Console on Account2 and I saw that the subdomain hosted zone was created and contained the necessary NS record as described here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/

When I **dig A <domain name>**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> A <domain name>
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 48891
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;<domain name>. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
<parent domain>.       300     IN      SOA     <xxxxxx>.com. <xxxx>.com. 1 14400 3600 604800 300

;; Query time: 100 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 01 20:11:12 PDT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 152
```

Comment: Have you bought your domain in R53, or somewhere else?

Comment: The domain may have been purchased with Google or GoDaddy and not R53 but I am unsure right now. Would that cause an issue?

Comment: `NXDOMAIN` means the domain does not exist, aka it was not registered. But your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: I posted here because I was wondering if my tf code was incorrect or was missing something.

Comment: If you want to use route53 to manage your domain trought a Hosted Zone first you have to point your DNS to AWS. Then you will be able to create DNS registers in a Hosted Zone.